# Adding asp.net code before doctype

Tags: html

Is this valid to do, I have asp.net code right before the !doctype html tag and It's throwing Internet Explorer into quirks mode...Can this code be added right after the doctype and still work just fine?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="somepage.index" %>

<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: Must be something else because that first line need to be there like that. Post the code behind file